# Angular 2, can't get data after subscribe in ngOnInit

Tags: angular, http, typescript, subscribe, ngoninit

I have a problem, maybe I don't understand how to do but when I try to catch data from an HttpRequest during angular ngOnInit, my console.log return me an "undefined" value. 
The thing is that when I use this value in my template view it works !

Here is my Component

```
export class ReferentielFormComponent implements OnInit {
  id: number;
  currentUser;
  referentiel;
  progressValue: number;
  formGroup: FormGroup;
  isNew: boolean;

  constructor(private service: AppService,
          private referentiels: ReferentielService,
          private router: ActivatedRoute,
          private config: NgbTabsetConfig) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.params.subscribe((params: Params) => this.id = params['id']);
    if (this.id) {
      this.referentiels.getReferentiel(this.id).subscribe(data => this.referentiel = data);
    } else {
      this.referentiel = {};
    }
    this.isNew = !this.referentiel;

    console.log(this.referentiel);
    console.log(this.isNew);
    this.progressValue = 20;

    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
      titre: new FormControl(!this.isNew ? this.referentiel.titre : '', [
        Validators.required,
      ]),
      description: new FormControl(!this.isNew ? this.referentiel.description : '', [
        Validators.required,
      ])
    });
  }
}
```

The variable this.referentiel return me an undefined so I can't bind my Form whith existing value because of that...

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Could `this.id` be null ?

Comment: This id is not null ! The problem is that this.referentiel is null the first time ngOnInit pass inside that function. I don't know why !

Comment: By default variables are undefined and hence referential is undefined. It becomes defined when a value is assigned to it. if the id is present it happens only in the subscribe function. By the time subscribe completes the console.log and formgroup would have already been executed

Comment: @KrishnanunniJeevan Yes I understand ! That is exactly my question :/ How should I do now ?

Comment: @ValentinFerey, as I have answered move the logic which uses the referentiel variable to  a common function. Call it from the else condition and inside the subscribe function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.referentiel is undefined till the subscribe completes. I think you have to move the formbuilder code to subscribe.




  ngOnInit() {
        this.router.params.subscribe((params: Params) => this.id = params['id']);
        if (this.id) {
            this.referentiels.getReferentiel(this.id).subscribe(data => {
                    this.referentiel = data;
                    this.buildForm(););
            }
            else {
                this.buildForm();
                this.referentiel = {};
            }
        }
        //Build form function
        buildForm() {
            this.isNew = !this.referentiel;
            this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
                titre: new FormControl(!this.isNew ? this.referentiel.titre : '', [
                    Validators.required,
                ]),
                description: new FormControl(!this.isNew ? this.referentiel.description : '', [
                    Validators.required,
                ])
            });
        }
```

Comment: This is not working... I have a new error : ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

Comment: That is different error . In your HTML  template are you setting the form element <form [formGroup]="formGroup" >

Comment: Yes I am, this error didn't exist before I changed the my code with yours :/

Comment: Can you wrap the form in a div and put an ngif.
<div *ngIf="!isNew  && !referentiel">. I have a feeling form is rendered before the subscription completes and throws this error

Comment: Sorry it should be *ngIf="isNew || referentiel". Alternatively you can set a boolean variable to false by default and set it to true inside buildForm function

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

**Type 1 :**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        this.load(params['id']);
    });
}

load(id) {
    this.id = id;
    console.log('this.id', this.id);
}
```

**Type 2 :**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        this.id = params['id'];
    }, () => {
        console.log('this.id', this.id);
    });
}
```

Comment: This id is not null ! The problem is that  this.referentiel is null the first time ngOnInit pass inside that function. I don't know why !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    ngOnInit() {
        this.router.params.subscribe((params: Params) => this.id = params['id']
        if (this.id) {
          this.referentiels.getReferentiel(this.id).subscribe(data => this.referentiel = data);
        } else {
          this.referentiel = {};
        }
        this.isNew = !this.referentiel;

        console.log(this.referentiel);
        console.log(this.isNew);
        this.progressValue = 20;

        this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
          titre: new FormControl(!this.isNew ? this.referentiel.titre : '', [
            Validators.required,
          ]),
          description: new FormControl(!this.isNew ? this.referentiel.description : '', [
            Validators.required,
          ])
        });
        );
      }
```

this.is isn't defined yet outside the subscribe.